# Finding minimum-cost circulations by canceling negative cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle

I'd like to solve the min-cost flow problem for graphs by cancelling negative cycles. Goldberg and Tarjan published a paper with this title in 1989 but I am unable to track down either a copy of the original or any more recent derived works that might explain the same algorithm.

Does anyone have a document that describes this algorithm or any code that implements it?

Comment: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=61051?

Comment: @bmargulies: Any chance of a free version? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find code for the Cycle-Canceling algorithm as well as other min-cost flow minimizers in the LEMON C++ library:

http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the classical "[Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013617549X)"